# PHP exec 'service httpd fullstatus' returns empty when run from cronjob

Tags: php, apache, cron, exec

I have this script that checks the server load. If the load is too high and/or the script is visited from a browser, the script fetches all running processes.

If the load is too high, and the script is run from a cron job, the running processes are mailed to me.

**My Problem is:**
When the load is too high, and the script is run from a cron job, `service httpd fullstatus` returns nothing. So I do receive an email stating the load. And even the `ps auxO-C | head` is shown in the e-mail. But just not the `service httpd fullstatus`

If the script is run from a browser, regardless of whether the load is too high, `service httpd fullstatus` and `ps auxO-C | head` both are shown ok.

I can't understand WHY this is... Can you guys help me? Do I have a typo somewhere, or am I missing some limitation/concept?

This is the crontab:

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/loadChecker.php
```

And this is the script `loadChecker.php`:

```
<?php

define('LOAD_TRIGGER',10); // threshold setting for when to mail the load

// get load average
if (function_exists("sys_getloadavg")){
    $content=sys_getloadavg();
    $load=$content[0];
    $content = implode(" " , $content);
}
else{
    $content = file_get_contents("/proc/loadavg");
    $loadavg = explode(" ", $content);
    $load = $loadavg[0] + 0;
}


if($load >= LOAD_TRIGGER) // check if load is too high
{
    // load is too high. If we are in a browser, show running processes, otherwise mail them.
    $ps = Array();
    exec("ps auxO-C | head", $ps);
    $ps = implode("\n", $ps);

    $hs = Array();
    exec("service httpd fullstatus", $hs);
    $hs = implode("\n", $hs);

    if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) // are we in a browser?
    {
        // yes we are. Let's show the PS and HTTPD fullstatus
        $output = str_replace("\n", "<br/>\n",  str_replace("  ", "&nbsp; ", $ps . "\n\n\n\n" . $hs)); // make it browser friendly
        $output = "<html><head></head><body>$output</body></html>";
        echo "Load is $content<br/>\n<br/>\n$output";
    }
    else
    {
        // no, we're not. Let's mail the PS and HTTPD fullstatus
        mail("me@here.com", "Load is $content", "$ps \n \n \n \n$hs "); // BUT THIS FAILS. THE PS IS SHOWN. BUT THE FULLSTATUS IS EMPTY IN THE MAIL
    }
}
else
{
    // load is OK. If we are in a browser, show running processes
    if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    {
        $ps = Array();
        exec("ps auxO-C | head", $ps);
        $ps = implode("\n", $ps);

        $hs = Array();
        exec("service httpd fullstatus", $hs);
        $hs = implode("\n", $hs);

        $output = str_replace("\n", "<br/>\n",  str_replace("  ", "&nbsp; ", $ps . "\n\n\n\n" . $hs)); // make it browser friendly
        $output = "<html><head></head><body>$output</body></html>";
        echo "Server load normaal ($content) op webserver3<br/>\n<br/>\n$output";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: browser v.s. command line are different environments. make sure that `/sbin` is the path of whatever shell the cli version of PHP is invoking. Otherwise it'll probably "command not found". That or try a full-blown absolute path, e.g. `exec('/sbin/service ...');`

Comment: i think you would be better of installing something like nargios for load checking then using a php script

Comment: @MarcB I already thought of this. But I was unable to find the `service` executable. D'oh! It's indeed just in the `/sbin/` folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to resolve if you use the full path. For example for centos you can use:

/sbin/service httpd fullstatus